# How to move specified line in file to other place with regexp match (bash script)?

Tags: regex, string, bash

OK, file contents:

```
asdasd0
**asdasd1**
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
**asdasd5**
asdasd6
```

I want to move "^asdasd5" RegEx matched line before "^asdasd1" RegEx matched line:

```
asdasd0
**asdasd5**
**asdasd1**
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
asdasd6
```

Howto?

Thanks

Comment: This is obviously not what you *really*  want to do. You shouldn't "dumb down" your example to a point where any answer you can get isn't going to work with your real data. Please show what your actual requirements are (and also what approaches you have already tried).

Comment: I think the question is not well edited, because the bold doesn't work inside code tags. I didn't fix it because I'm not sure. Do it yourself to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your pattern is - what is constant, and what is changing.

```
sed "/.*5/d;/.*1/i"$(sed -n '/.*5/p' FILE)  FILE
```

I delete the line containing a 5, and insert that line behind the line containing the 1.

You can't work with -i here, since the file is his own reference.

```
sed "/.*5/d;/.*1/i"$(sed -n '/.*5/p' FILE)  FILE > FILE.tmp 
mv FILE.tmp FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using `ex`:

```
ex inputfile <<'EOF'
/^asdasd5
d
/^asdasd1
-
put
wq
EOF
```

The same thing all on one line:

```
printf '%s\n' '/^asdasd5' 'd' '/^asdasd1' '-' 'put' 'wq' | ex inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`:

```
s/^(asdasd1.*)(^asdasd5(?:\n|$))/$2$1/sm
```

An example. Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $data;

## Read all DATA content into $data variable.
do { 
    $/ = undef;
    $data = <DATA>;
};

## Last 's' flag lets '.*' match newlines.
## 'm' flag lets '^' and '$' match at the beginning or end of each line.
$data =~ s/^(asdasd1.*)(^asdasd5(?:\n|$))/$2$1/sm;

print $data;

__DATA__
asdasd0
asdasd1
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
asdasd5
asdasd6
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following output:

```
asdasd0
asdasd5
asdasd1
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
asdasd6
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/asdasd1/,/asdasd5/{/asdasd5/{G;b};/asdasd1/{h;d};H;d}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is line-oriented, you don't really need a regular expression for this. When you see the start line, begin to capture the lines. When you see the ending line, print it, print the captured lines, and then print the rest of the file:

```
awk -v start=asdasd1 -v end=asdasd5 '
    match($0,start) {capture=1}
    match($0,end)   {print $0 captured; capture=0; next}
    capture         {captured = captured RS $0; next}
    1
'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is a simple awk double-pass algorithm:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { if ($0 ~ /asdasd5/) t=$0; next }
     /asdasd5/ { next }
     /asdasd1/ { print t }
     1' file file
```

Answer (score -1):

use sed's command 'i' to insert before pattern.
See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-41