# Moving matching lines in a text file using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to follow the post

[How to move specified line in file to other place with regexp match (bash script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499960/how-to-move-specified-line-in-file-to-other-place-with-regexp-match-bash-script)

to my example file

```
asdasd0
-SRC_OUT_DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
asdasd6
```

The final output should look like

```
asdasd0
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
-SRC_OUT_DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
asdasd6
```

I have tried the following

```
sed "/-SRC_OUT_DIR.*/d;/DEFAULTS { /a"$(sed -n '/-SRC_OUT_DIR.*/p' test.txt)  test.txt`
```

but it is not working. I get the following output

```
sed:can't read =: No such file or directory
sed:can't read "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g": No such file or directory
asdasd0
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
-SRC_OUT_DIR
asdasd6
```

I am also wondering why can't I use `\1`, `\2` to print the line that needs to be moved. I tried that but it prints nothing. How would I write a `sed` command if I need to move multiple matching lines to different places in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you ask a `sed` solution I would propose to use `awk` for this.
Using an ugly nesting of a multitude of `sed` commands is not really recommended. Especially because you read your file twice.

Here is an awk

```
awk '/SRC_OUT_DIR/{t=$0;next}1;/DEFAULTS/{print t}' file
```

**How does it work?**

awk will read your `file` line by line. Per line, it will do the following three commands one after the other:

1. **`/SRC_OUT_DIR/{t=$0;next}`:** if the line contains a substring matching `SRC_OUT_DIR`, then store the line in a variable `t` and move to the `next` line (don't execute 2 and 3)
2. **`1`:** default action: print the line
3. **`/DEFAULTS/{print t}`:** if the current line contains the substring `DEFAULTS`, print the line stored in variable `t`

If you have multiple lines to move (this only moves downwards):

```
awk '/pattern1/ {t[1]=$0;next}
     /pattern2/ {t[2]=$0;next}
     /pattern3/ {t[3]=$0;next}
     /target3/ { print t[3] }
     1
     /target1/ { print t[1] }
     /target2/ { print t[2] }' file
```

note that `pattern3` will be printed before `target3`.

Comment: could you explain the syntax so newbies like me and others can understand. How to do this for multiple lines?

Comment: @tulamba explanation added. What do you mean with multiple lines?

Comment: awesome explanation

Comment: @tulamba If this answered the question, feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer. I noticed that you did not upvote any answer to any of your questions. It is recommended to do so. Pay it forward as a figure of speech. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: multiple lines mean if I have to move multiple lines that match a pattern to a different place in a file

Comment: @tulamba added an example. But you could ask a new question which expands on this question with a clean example (as you did here)

Comment: shouldn't there be a ; after 1 in the multiple line solution?

Comment: @tulamba no,  because it is not written as a one-liner but spread over multiple lines. The semi-colon (;) is only used to split between `pattern {action}` pairs if need be in one-liners. Note that `1` means `1 { print $0 }` which is equivalent to `{print $0}`

Comment: what if pattern2 needs to be applied only once and skipped for rest of the matches.

Comment: @tulamba that is a new question.

Comment: I would love to post a new question but there is a 90 minute restriction on posting. Now it is up to you

Comment: @tulamba there is a 90 min restriction? :-\

Answer (score 4):

You could store the matching line in the [hold](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-h-_0028hold_0029-command) space, [delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-d-_0028delete_0029-command) it and then [append](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-G-_0028appending-Get_0029-command) the hold space to the line after which you want to insert:

```
$ sed '/^-SRC_OUT_DIR/{h;d;};/^DEFAULTS {/G' infile
asdasd0
asdasd2
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
-SRC_OUT_DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
asdasd6
```

Comment: It works! Thaks a lot! One question: this work but only for one line. It is possible to move multiple lines who match a pattern and append them after (or beofre) a specific line who matches another pattern? For example, move more lines who match ^-SRC_OUT_DIR and move all of them after ^DEFAULTS?

Comment: @Magallo Without spending too much time, something like `sed '/^-SRC_OUT_DIR/{H;d;};/^DEFAULTS {/{G;s/\n//;}'` would work; `H` instead of `h` appends to the hold space instead of replacing it; because the hold space then starts with a blank line, we delete that blank line after appending to the pattern space with `G`.