# Match only very first occurrence of a pettern using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to follow the solution at

[Moving matching lines in a text file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147798/moving-matching-lines-in-a-text-file-using-sed)

The situation is that pattern2 needs to be applied just once in the whole file. How can I change the following to get this done

```
awk '/pattern1/ {t[1]=$0;next}
     /pattern2/ {t[2]=$0;next}
     /pattern3/ {t[3]=$0;next}
     /target3/ { print t[3] }
     1
     /target1/ { print t[1] }
     /target2/ { print t[2] }' file
```

Here is the file on which I applied the pattern2 (RELOC_DIR)

```
asdasd0
-SRC_OUT_DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
RELOC_DIR = /i/j/k/l/m
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
asdasd6
$(RELOC_DIR)/some other text1
$(RELOC_DIR)/some other text2
$(RELOC_DIR)/some other text3
$(RELOC_DIR)/some other text4
```

and the last 4 lines of the file got deleted because of the match.

```
asdasd0
-SRC_OUT_DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
asdasd3
asdasd4
DEFAULTS {
RELOC_DIR = /i/j/k/l/m
asdasd6
```

Comment: If there are multiple occurrences of pattern2, which one is to be moved?

Comment: @jhnc only the first occurence. Others have to be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you need to check `pattern2` along with some other condition if this is the case then try.

```
awk '/pattern1/ {t[1]=$0;next}
     /pattern2/ && /check_other_text_in_current_line/{t[2]=$0;next}
     /pattern3/ {t[3]=$0;next}
     /target3/ { print t[3] }
     1
     /target1/ { print t[1] }
     /target2/ { print t[2] }' file
```

Above is checking `check_other_text_in_current_line` string(which is a sample and you could change it as per your actual string) is present along with pattern2 also in same line. If this si not what you are looking for then please post samples of input and expected output in your post.

---

---

OR in case you are looking that only 1st match for `pattern2` in Input_file and skip all others then try. It will only print very first match for pattern2 and skip all others.(since samples are not provied by OP so this code is written only for the ask of specific pattern matching)

```
awk '/pattern1/ {t[1]=$0;next}
     /pattern2/ && ++count==1{t[2]=$0;next}
     /pattern3/ {t[3]=$0;next}
     /target3/ { print t[3] }
     1
     /target1/ { print t[1] }
     /target2/ { print t[2] }' file
```

***OR***

```
awk '/pattern1/ {t[1]=$0;next}
     /pattern2/ && !found2{t[2]=$0;found2=1;next}
     /pattern3/ {t[3]=$0;next}
     /target3/ { print t[3] }
     1
     /target1/ { print t[1] }
     /target2/ { print t[2] }' file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Though my 2nd solution looks like should be the one as per OP's ask but complete picture of requirement is not given so adding code only for printing Pattern2(string `RELOC_DIR`)'s first occurence here.

```
awk '/RELOC_DIR/ && ++ count==1{print}'  Input_file
RELOC_DIR = /i/j/k/l/m
```

***OR***

```
awk '!found2 && /RELOC_DIR/ { t[2]=$0; found2=1; print}' Input_file
```

Comment: In general, it's probably fractionally more efficient to check count first so you don't have to perform redundant regexp matches: `!found2 && /pattern2/ { t[2]=$0; found2=1; next; }`

Comment: @jhnc, sure, added it to my solutions now. To be honest I added that count style since it could be easy for understanding of OP/users that condition will be true when its match count is 1. Thanks for helping here to improve it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please let me know how can i give you a complete picture

Comment: @tulamba, IMHO, open a new thread. Then mention 3 simple things,1st- sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd- your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem. Also be clear in logic(s) may not be programming side but from getting expected output side(how we could achieve expected output(shown by you) etc). Once you do this with all/complete information I am pretty sure you will get full guidance on your question(which you are getting now too :) ) cheers and keep enjoying on this great site SO.